# .bash_profile or .bashrc for shell in emacs?

Tags: shell, bash

I wrote an alias for a huge command and stored it in `.bash_profile` and to my surprise, emacs didn't pick up the alias that I wrote in `.bash_profile`. After some searching in the internet, I created a `.bashrc` file in my $HOME with the alias command and only after that emacs picked up the alias. I'm confused because *terminal.app* takes alias from `.bash_profile` but emacs takes alias only in `.bashrc`.

I was running <kbd>M-x shell</kbd> and I'm on macOS. Can someone explain me what's the relationship with emacs and `.bashrc` & `.bash_profile`.

More to the point, **how can I get Emacs to read my `.bash_profile` in addition to `.bashrc`?**

Comment: How did you get Emacs to pick up your `.bashrc` aliases? I'm asking this because my Emacs (and [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163591/bash-autocompletion-in-emacs-shell-mode) others') doesn't do it by default.

Comment: @ArchStanton see @Vera Johanna answer to this question. That is the same method I used. Though now I'm using `zsh` instead of bash :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour. `.bash_profile` is for so-called login shells. Like when you log in to your computer in text mode, or in a terminal emulator to a different computer via `ssh` or `telnet` or ...

`.bashrc` is meant for non-login shells, like when you are already logged in and start a new xterm, or in this case emacs' `shell` mode.

Usually the `.bash_profile` contains commands to read in the `.bashrc`, too:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

so the `.bashrc` is read at every startup.

---

So, aliases belong into `.bashrc`; it is also customary to create a separate `.bash_aliases` and include it in `.bashrc` via the same construct:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Comment: emacs now starts up with zsh so you may consider copying the contents of .bash_profile into .zshrc

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the points made by @pingi, you can also use a separate configuration file that will be loaded only for the emacs shell (`M-x shell`):

From the manual page [(emacs) Interactive Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html):

> Emacs sends the new shell the contents of the file
>   ‘~/.emacs_SHELLNAME’ as input, if it exists, where SHELLNAME is the name
>   of the file that the shell was loaded from.  For example, if you use
>   bash, the file sent to it is ‘~/.emacs_bash’.  If this file is not
>   found, Emacs tries with ‘~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh’.

This is useful if you want to use a different shell prompt format within Emacs, or to define functions for passing files to emacsclient.