# Emacs shell not picking aliases from bashrc

Tags: shell-command

NOT Working: `/bin/bash: Psu: command not found`

```
M-! cmd Psu
```

Working

```
M-! cmd ls
```

##### .bashrc

```
cat ~/.bashrc | grep Psu
cat ~/.bashrc | grep aliases

 alias Psu='sudo pacman -Syyu'
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
```

##### .bash_profile

```
cat ~/.bash_profile | grep -A 2 bashrc

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

##### .bash_aliases

```
cat ~/.bash_aliases

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

I've read and followed: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28999/21118

What am I missing?

Comment: From your comments to the answer below it appears you are using eshell. Eshell is a terminal emulator written entirely in elisp. It doesn't run bash or zsh, it is a separate stand-alone program. As such it uses its own configuration, and won't read any if the bash files. If you want to run bash in Emacs, look at `M-x shell` or `M-x term`

Comment: the question you link to asks about `M-x shell`, not `M-x eshell`

Comment: I answered a similar question a while ago.  Check this out:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74388/37580

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html):

> To specify the shell file name used by M-x shell, customize the variable `explicit-shell-file-name`. If this is nil (the default), Emacs uses the environment variable ESHELL if it exists. Otherwise, it usually uses the variable `shell-file-name`

You obviously want to use `bash` shell; may I suggest a piece of my Emacs configuration:

```
;; make emacs recognize my bash aliases and functions & use bash as default shell                                                                                              
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")                                                                                                                                    
(setq shell-file-name "bash")                                                                                                                                                  
(setq explicit-bash.exe-args '("--noediting" "--login" "-ic"))                                                                                                                 
(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")                                                                                                                                              
(setenv "SHELL" shell-file-name)
```

Comment: What does the flag "-i" does to `shell-command-switch`?

Comment: Interactive, makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. Still no .bashrc aliases in eshell. Tried [0] as well. Any other suggestions? [0] https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/71234/12999