# Is there any way of making eshell aliases using bash and zsh aliases syntax?

Tags: eshell, aliases

Let's say I have a file called `.alias` in my `$HOME` directory with the following content:

```
alias "my-first-alias"="ls -lha"
alias "my-second-alias="echo 'Hello World'"
```

I know that if put the line `source "$HOME/.alias"` in both my `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` files I'll be able to create aliases on these shells at the same time in a single file, just so I don't have to manually copy one alias that I have just created in .bashrc to .zshrc...

So far everything is fine... The problem starts with `eshell`, its alias syntax is different, the last two aliases in `eshell` syntax would be the following:

```
alias my-first-alias 'ls -lha'
alias my-second-alias 'echo "Hello World"'
```

Since its syntax is different I can't just source my `.alias` file for `eshell`, I wouldn't like to manually translate my aliases for the eshell syntax all the times that I create a new alias. Is there any standard way of solving problems like this on emacs? Or should I be thinking about how to create a script that will translate my bash aliases to eshell aliases for sourcing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go over to [EshellAlias](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias) on EmacsWiki, there are many solutions to this problem.  The one by [Edgar Vincent](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Edgar_Vincent) that's currently at the very bottom of the page is the most concise and elegant solution so far.

```lisp
  (defun eshell-load-bash-aliases ()
    "Read Bash aliases and add them to the list of eshell aliases."
    ;; Bash needs to be run - temporarily - interactively
    ;; in order to get the list of aliases.
      (with-temp-buffer
        (call-process "bash" nil '(t nil) nil "-ci" "alias")
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward "alias \\(.+\\)='\\(.+\\)'$" nil t)
          (eshell/alias (match-string 1) (match-string 2)))))

  ;; We only want Bash aliases to be loaded when Eshell loads its own aliases,
  ;; rather than every time `eshell-mode' is enabled.
  (add-hook 'eshell-alias-load-hook 'eshell-load-bash-aliases)
```

It reads the output of `bash -ci alias` and loops through them to run `eshell/alias` on each alias it finds.  It should implicitly load your `$HOME/.alias` file.

The function `eshell/alias` in the `eshell-laod-bash-aliases` above writes the list of aliases to the file `eshell-aliases-file` after each addition of one alias.
That may take long for long alias lists. The following version writes the list only after processing all aliases from bash.

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun eshell-load-bash-aliases ()
  "Read Bash aliases and add them to the list of eshell aliases."
  ;; Bash needs to be run - temporarily - interactively
  ;; in order to get the list of aliases.
  (with-temp-buffer
    (call-process "bash" nil '(t nil) nil "-ci" "alias")
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'eshell-write-aliases-list) #'ignore))
      (while (re-search-forward "alias \\(.+\\)='\\(.+\\)'$" nil t)
        (eshell/alias (match-string 1) (match-string 2))))
    (eshell-write-aliases-list)))

;; We only want Bash aliases to be loaded when Eshell loads its own aliases,
;; rather than every time `eshell-mode' is enabled.
(add-hook 'eshell-alias-load-hook 'eshell-load-bash-aliases)
```

Comment: Thanks! Even though it worked fine it seems that emacs loads this function on the run all the times that I open `eshell` for the first time on emacs... Since I have a lot of aliases this solution is slow for my case (it takes around 40 seconds to start)... I'm not sure if there's a workaround with a elisp solution. But I've realized the bash solution on the page from your link works immediately... Probably writing a bash script that watches changes on my `.alias` file and rewrites a second `.alias_eshell` file works better for me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many aliases do you have?  40 seconds is a long time just to load aliases.

Comment: Well, it's an old file with aliases and I don't really know all of them by heart. But there are 131 aliases. I've also tested with an empty `.alias` file and in this case this solution works immediately. Apparently, 131 is a huge number for elisp, I'm not sure if it's only that though...

Comment: @raylight Please, try again with the modified version at the bottom of this answer.

Comment: @Tobias Thank you for that speed optimization.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks, with the second sample of code it works immediately for me now.